# How to get a set of keys with largest values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working on a function

```
def common_words(dictionary, N):
     if len(dictionary) > N:
         max(dictionary, key=dictionary.get)
```

Description of the function is:

> The first parameter is the dictionary of word counts and the second is
>   a positive integer N. This function should update the dictionary so
>   that it includes the most common (highest frequency words). At most N
>   words should be included in the dictionary. If including all words
>   with some word count would result in a dictionary with more than N
>   words, then none of the words with that word count should be included.
>   (i.e., in the case of a tie for the N+1st most common word, omit all
>   of the words in the tie.)

So I know that I need to get the N items with the highest values but I am not sure how to do that. I also know that once I get N items that if there are any duplicate values that I need to pop them out.

---

For example, given

```
k = {'a':5, 'b':4, 'c':4, 'd':1}
```

then

```
common_words(k, 2)
```

should modify `k` so that it becomes `{'a':5}`.

Comment: please provide sample input and output

Comment: >>> k= {'a':5,'b':4,'c':4,'d':1}                                                                                          
>>> common_words(k,2)
should return 'a'

Comment: Can you please, explain your problem with examples ? I didn't get the logic behind your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my algorithm as below

1. 1st build tuple list from dictionary sorted based on value from
   largest to smallest
2. check for if item[N-1] match item[N] value, if yes, drop item[N-1]
   (index start from 0, so -1 there)
3. finally, convert the slice of tuple list up to N element back to
   dict, may change to use `OrderedDict` here if wanna retain the items order

it will just return the dictionary as it is if the dictionary length is less than N

```
def common_words(dictionary, N):
    if len(dictionary) > N:
        tmp = [(k,dictionary[k]) for k in sorted(dictionary, key=dictionary.get, reverse=True)]
        if tmp[N-1][1] == tmp[N][1]:
            N -= 1
        return dict(tmp[:N])
        # return [i[0] for i in tmp[:N]] # comment line above and uncomment this line to get keys only as your title mention how to get keys
    else:
        return dictionary
        # return dictionary.keys() # comment line above and uncomment this line to get keys only as your title mention how to get keys

>>> common_words({'a':5, 'b':4, 'c':4, 'd':1}, 2)
{'a': 5}
```

OP wanna modify input dictionary within function and return `None`, it can be modified as below

```
def common_words(dictionary, N):
    if len(dictionary) > N:
        tmp = [(k,dictionary[k]) for k in sorted(dictionary, key=dictionary.get, reverse=True)]
        if tmp[N-1][1] == tmp[N][1]:
            N -= 1
        # return dict(tmp[:N])
        for i in tmp[N:]:
            dictionary.pop(i[0])

>>> k = {'a':5, 'b':4, 'c':4, 'd':1}
>>> common_words(k, 2)
>>> k
{'a': 5}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Helped me a lot. One question however, I tried changing the code so that it returns nothing, and that you would have to recall on the dictionary for it to output it but I couldn't figure it out. So an example:  
>>> k={'lets':3,'go':2,'and':2,'by':1}
>>> common_words(k,2)
>>> k
{'lets:3}

Comment: if i get you right, you want input dictionary to become output of `common_words` function, easier way to do this is `k=common_words(k,2)`, another way is to change the line `return dict(tmp[:N])` into `for i in tmp[N:]:dictionary.pop(i[0])` , this way it will modify the input dictionary within function

Comment: i wanted the function to return None, so that when the function is run they would have to type in dictionary again to get the value like the example i posted   they would need to ask for k again to get the answer

Comment: refer updated answer based on what i suggest in the comment

Comment: Thanks! i read this "for i in tmp[N:]:dictionary.pop(i[0]" as one line and got confused. Thanks for the help again

Answer (score 2):

Here's my algorithm for this problem.

1. Extract the data from the dictionary into a list and sort it in descending order on the dictionary values.
2. Clear the original dictionary.
3. Group the sorted data into groups that have the same value.
4. Re-populate the dictionary with the all (key, value) pairs from each group in the sorted list if that will keep the total dictionary size <= N. If adding a group would make the total dictionary size > N, then return.

The grouping operation can be easily done using the standard [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function.

To perform the sorting and grouping we need an appropriate key function, as described in the `groupby`, [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) and [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) docs. Since we need the second item of each tuple we *could* use

```
def keyfunc(t):
    return t[1]
```

or

```
keyfunc = lambda t: t[1]
```

but it's more efficient to use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

---

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

def common_words(d, n):
    keyfunc = itemgetter(1)
    lst = sorted(d.items(), key=keyfunc, reverse=True)
    d.clear()
    for _, g in groupby(lst, key=keyfunc):
        g = list(g)
        if len(d) + len(g) <= n:
            d.update(g)
        else:
            break

# test

data = {'a':5, 'b':4, 'c':4, 'd':1} 

common_words(data, 4)
print(data)
common_words(data, 2)
print(data)
```

**output**

```
{'c': 4, 'd': 1, 'b': 4, 'a': 5}
{'a': 5}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply! I haven't seen some of those functions like itemgetter and groupby. can you explain them and what alternatives i can use in there place?

Comment: It is just practice homework :) I am trying to practice dictionaries

Comment: You know, you could just *look up the functions in the documentation*

Comment: @EnesDal I've added a little more explanation and some links to the official documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!